# Loading jQuery UI in the head

Tags: plugins, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to load jquery-ui-core and jquery-ui-slider in the head of my theme. Here is my code:

```
function load_jquery_ui() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-slider' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_jquery_ui' );
```

The jQuery UI loads in the footer. But because I have some inline scripting (due to php implementation in the JS) I need it to load in the head. Anyone that has any idea how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually. This answer is the only correct answer.

If you need jQuery for a certain script just add it as necessary in the jQuery array.

```
wp_register_script( 'ytc-admin-scripts', YTC_URL . 'admin/admin-functions.js', array( 'jquery','jquery-ui-slider' ), '1.0');
```